# How to prove distributive property on Existentials?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I'm trying to prove that ∃x(F(x) ∨ G(x)) is equivalent to (ExF(x) ∨ ExG(x)). Honestly I'm quite stumped. I get how to to do it with numbers by distributing, but I can't wrap my head around it in FOL. I read some examples on how to do it online but none of them really answer my question or use rules that I haven't learned. Or they take something for fact, without showing that proof.

My initial hunch was to
1: Use Existential Elimination
2: Assume F(a)
3:Use Existential Introduction ExF(x)
4: Use disjunction introduction for ExF(x) v ExG(x)

But all proof checkers I've used said that it was incorrect. I assume it's because the end of the proof is not the same as my initial premise.

Comment: What are your axioms for FOL?

Comment: Your first step is correct: assume Fa or Ga fir existential elimination. At this stage you have to use disjunction elimination to derive ExFx or ExGx under both cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My initial hunch was to:
>
> 1: Use Existential Elimination
>
> 2: Assume $F(a)$
>
> 3:Use Existential Introduction $\exists x \ F(x)$
>
> 4: Use disjunction introduction for $\exists x \ F(x) \lor \exists x \ G(x)$

No, that is very much incomplete.

Note that you have shown that you can prove $\exists x \ F(x) \lor \exists x \ G(x)$ *under the assumption of* $F(a)$. While helpful, that is not enough.

Note that when in step 1 you use Existential Elimination on $\exists x (F(x) \lor G(x))$, you get $F(a) \lor G(a)$. That is: you know that either $F(a)$ is true *or* that $G(a)$ is true.

Now, again, you have shown that in the case that $F(a)$ is true, you get your desired result $\exists x \ F(x) \lor \exists x \ G(x)$.  But what if $G(a)$ is true?  You'll have to show that when $G(a)$ is the case, you *also* can get to $\exists x \ F(x) \lor \exists x \ G(x)$.  And once you've shown that, you'll have to use Proof by Cases (probably formalized by some Disjunction Elimination rule  ... but this all depends on the details of the specific proof system you use) to finally conclude that $\exists x \ F(x) \lor \exists x \ G(x)$ is true, merely on the basis of $\exists x (F(x) \lor G(x))$ (i.e. no longer dependent on assumption $F(a)$ or $G(a)$)

Second, since you had to show the *equivalence* between $\exists x (F(x) \lor G(x))$ and $\exists x \ F(x) \lor \exists x \ G(x)$, you still have to go the other way around as well. That is, after showing that you can derive $\exists x \ F(x) \lor \exists x \ G(x)$ from $\exists x (F(x) \lor G(x))$, you also need to show that you can derive $\exists x (F(x) \lor G(x))$ from $\exists x \ F(x) \lor \exists x \ G(x)$

Comment: Hi, I solved the argument. But I was wondering what would I do if the problem was a theorem?

Comment: @mivology1 You mean the biconditional between the two statements?  Then do the two proofs as two subproofs and then use biconditional introduction